# What Constellation Is This? (Photo Included)

Tags: star, identify-this-object, constellations

Observed on 9th of Jan 2021 in Newcastle Upon Tyne (UK) looking WSW at a little after Midnight.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If it was rather small, I suppose you were looking at the Pleiades, which is an open star cluster (not a constellation).
Take a look at this web application: https://stellarium-web.org/
You can set a time and location and find constellations and other objects really easily.

Comment: Not a constellation indeed, but can be considered an asterism (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterism_(astronomy) ) . The "mini dipper".

Answer (score 15):

Yes, those are the [Pleiades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleiades). The form corresponds exactly to the photo below:

[image: Pleiades + Venus]

(source: [Star-Gazing](https://www.star-gazing.co.uk/WebPage/wp-content/uploads/Venus-Pleiades-20200402.png) - the disk below the Pleiades is Venus, this is a photo from April)

As @theWrongAlice says, they're not a constellation, but they are part of Taurus (the Bull).

Comment: Is it just me, or does Glorfindel look like Alexander Armstrong?

Answer (score 9):

In such situations, I find [Astrometry.net](https://astrometry.net/) particularly helpful. Feeding it your image, I got this result:

[image]

Of course, the stars Pleione, Sterope, and Taygeta are enough to identify [the Pleiades](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Pleiades#/Brightest_stars).

While in this case it's fairly easy to identify the Pleiades by inspection alone and verify this, for less recognisable cases Astrometry.net is a very handy tool. They've got an [online version](http://nova.astrometry.net/), where you upload a photo and the recognition is done server-side, or you could install the app, either from repos or [build from source](https://astrometry.net/use.html).

Comment: Thanks. That's a great resource.